# Visual Studio 2008, asks about encoding everytime I open a page

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

Everytime I open a file in vs2008, it asks me about fixing the encoding.
it also, if the file is open, asks me if I want to close the file before showing it.

I'm pretty sure I fixed this issue once before, but I can't remember how.

Does anyone remember how to fix it?

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: I always hated this.  IIRC, it usually boiled down to either something the source control system was doing or another editor wasn't preserving the encoding correctly.  Thankfully I haven't run into it in VS2010 (yet ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the fix:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/vssetup/thread/35fcbb4d-3511-4f79-b3cd-6d05883b4c6f

basically the default editor for .cs files was set to "CSharp Editor (with encoding)"

Change the default back to the non "(with encoding)" flavor of the editor and beauty and joy are once again a part of you life!

Cal-

Comment: I was seeing this problem with VS 2015 when opening C++ standard library header files that don't have a file extension, like <vector>. I was able to change the default open-with editor type.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are editing your files with more than one editor, chances are you are saving with different encodings.  Visual studio can detect this and try to recover the file.  Try to save your files to a common encoding (via "Save As") and make sure that all text editors you are using on that file support the encoding you selected.

Comment: but if that was al lthat was going on, I'd open the file, get the popup, close the file , repoen the file and not get the popup... alas I'm gettign it eveytime, even if I open and close it in series.
(I'm also not using multiple editors, but I am opening .rdlc fiels as xml to edit them, which is whenthe problem started) thanks,.